# Initialization of the class variable

Tags: java

I have 4 java classes in a maven project

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
Test4
```

**Test4 class has the following static variable and static method:**

```
private static Test4 instance=new Test4();

public static Test4 getInstance(){
  return instance;
}
```

This function is getting invoked from Test1,Test2 and Test3 class and I would get the same value of instance returned for ex:Test4@7dfda.

First time when this function getInstance() is invoked from Test1 then it could have initialized the Test4 class and initialized the static class variable which is instance. Won't it be behaving the same when this function is getting invoked again from Test2 or Test3 class and I should get the new value of instance returned everytime?

Comment: I do not understand the question really but what you have here is a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and you can read up on that.

Comment: What is the actual outcome, what do you expect the outcome to be, do the two not line up, in what way do they differ?

Comment: there is no initalization in the way you describe happening. the variable `instance` is intialized before `main` is called, therefore before `getInstance` is called. `getInstance` simply returns a copy of the variable `instance`

Comment: Well, each class is initialized when it is referenced in the code.  The first time `Test4` is referenced or used in some way, that .class file is loaded and initialized.  The JVM spec requires this, and NOT that a class is loaded and initialized "before main."  But most times you can't tell the difference, so it's always "before you code can see any effects."

Comment: ok there is no main method... I m using mvn clean install command that executes the code which is inside the plugin... i was thinking that everytime the getinstance method is invoked the Test4 class is getting initialized and it should return a new value everytime

Comment: no, that is exact opposite what the code does and what a singleton is supposed to do. The purpose is that no matter how often and from where you call it to return the exact same instance every single time.

Comment: If a new JVM is started each time, or if the class is unloaded, yes a new object will be created for `getInstance()`.  But you haven't given us enough details to say if that is happening.

Comment: If you want a fresh instance, you should have used ``return new Testt4;``.

Comment: all 4 classes are getting executed one by one.. will the initialization of the Test4 class occur everytime when getInstance method is called from all the classes -Test1,2,3? And if it initializes everytime then instance variable will have a new value or the same previous value?

Comment: *"all 4 classes are getting executed one by one"* - that is not how anything works. Unless you give us more context we cannot answer anything here. What is executed at what point, by whom?

Answer (score 1):

This is a **broken** singleton implementation. The `instance` field should have been made `final`.

Whenever the JVM executes code, it first does a scan of all the various types mentioned in the method that the VM is about to execute. It then first looks up all those types, asking the relevant classloader for these classes.

In other words, when you have:

```
class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test1();
        System.out.println(Test2.someStaticMethod());
        System.out.println(Test3.class.getName());
    }
}
```

and `main` is to be executed, first the VM does that scan and realizes that it needs Test1, Test2, and Test3 to be loaded or this is not going to work out. So, the VM asks the relevant classloader (as this is 'main' we are talking about, the default app loader which uses the classpath) for Test1, Test2, and Test3.

Classloaders act like a big hashmap, mapping class names to the loaded equivalent. So, if Test1, Test2, or Test3 are already loaded, they just immediately return the already loaded class. It gets more interesting if they were *not* loaded.

However, loading Test1 will in turn cause Test4 to retrieved (that is, if Test1's initialization itself makes calls to Test4. If Test1's constructor and initializers do nothing with Test4, loading Test1 will not cause Test4 to be loaded). Test4 hasn't been loaded yet, so it will be loaded. Loading Test2 will again cause Test4 to be retrieved, but it was already loaded.

As part of actually loading a class, all static initializers are run; that's where that `new Test4()` ended up. Given that a class is only loaded once, the `new Test4()` in `private static Test4 instance = new Test4()` is only ever executed one time.

Of course, if `new Test4()` is only ever executed once in the lifetime of a VM, there can only be 1 Test4 instance.

The complete code for a proper singleton is:

```
public class Test4 {
    // important: a private constructor,
    // to ensure nobody can make instances.
    private Test4() {}

    private static final Test4 INSTANCE = new Test4();
    public static Test4 get() { return instance; }
}
```

Thus, what you are observing is correct: getInstance() returns `instance`, and instance is initialized only once: The first time anybody calls `getInstance()`, or rather right before that moment in time: The first time any method is executed whose body does something with `Test4` (and, what could it be doing, other than invoking `getInstance()`? Nothing, most likely).

NB:

It is **extremely** common to see creative and almost always broken or needlessly convoluted ways to make singletons. It's one of those tonguemap/inuit have 1000 words for snow/planes fly because air goes faster under the wing than above the wing/frogs stay in a pot if you increase the heat slowly kind of deals: **extremely** widespread and widely believed complete hogwash. So, if you go on an internet search spree on singletons, beware that the majority of posts you will find are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that the "instance" object (and "getInstance" method) are **Static**.

**A static method / member are shared to all calls of the method, regardeless of the specific object that is being used.**